# tried autoencoder with my custom dataset but got stuck on autoencoder.fit

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, keras

Here i have tried to create a directory with my own image data with train and val directory folder having dog and cat as two folders(which is labels) inside my directory folder and tried to fit it in autoencoder, i tried lots of tricks but didnt worked can any one please help me out with this.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from keras import Input, Model
from keras.datasets import mnist
from keras.layers import Dense, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, UpSampling2D
import pandas as pd
import os
import random
import seaborn as sns
from math import *
from matplotlib.image import imread
import random
import string
import cv2

os.chdir("C:\\Users\\Lenovo\\OneDrive\\Desktop")

# insert the name of zip file
filename = "train2 (2)"
file_name = f'{filename}.zip'

folder_name = ''.join('CNN'+'_' + str(random.choice(range(10, 1001))))

from zipfile import ZipFile
zip = ZipFile(file_name)
zip.extractall(folder_name)

my_data_dir = os.path.abspath(folder_name)

data = os.listdir(my_data_dir)[0]

path = my_data_dir+'\\'+ data

import splitfolders
splitfolders.ratio(path, output=folder_name, seed=1337, ratio=(.7, 0.3))

test = os.listdir(my_data_dir)[2]
train = os.listdir(my_data_dir)[1]

test_path = my_data_dir+'\\'+test
train_path = my_data_dir+'\\'+train

dim1 = []
dim2 = []
for cls in os.listdir(test_path):
    for image_filename in os.listdir(test_path+'\\'+cls):
        img = imread(test_path+ '\\'+ cls +'\\'+image_filename)
        d1,d2,colors = img.shape
        dim1.append(d1)
        dim2.append(d2)

d1 = round(np.mean(dim1))
d2 = round(np.mean(dim2))

image_shape = (d1,d2,3)
print(image_shape)

from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
image_gen = ImageDataGenerator(rotation_range=20, # rotate the image 20 degrees
                               width_shift_range=0.10, # Shift the pic width by a max of 5%
                               height_shift_range=0.10, # Shift the pic height by a max of 5%
                               rescale=1/255, # Rescale the image by normalzing it.
                               shear_range=0.1, # Shear means cutting away part of the image (max 10%)
                               zoom_range=0.1, # Zoom in by 10% max
                               horizontal_flip=True, # Allo horizontal flipping
                               fill_mode='nearest' # Fill in missing pixels with the nearest filled value
                              )

image_gen.flow_from_directory(train_path)
image_gen.flow_from_directory(test_path)

from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Activation, Dropout, Flatten, Dense, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from tensorflow.keras.layers import BatchNormalization

image_shape_prod = image_shape[0]*image_shape[1]*image_shape[2]
image_shape_prod

batch_size = 20
train_image_gen = image_gen.flow_from_directory(train_path,
                                               target_size=image_shape[:2],
                                                color_mode='rgb',
                                               batch_size=batch_size,
                                               class_mode='binary')

test_image_gen = image_gen.flow_from_directory(test_path,
                                               target_size=image_shape[:2],
                                               color_mode='rgb',
                                               batch_size=batch_size,
                                               class_mode='binary',shuffle=False)

encoder = Sequential()
encoder.add(Flatten(input_shape=[28,28]))
encoder.add(Dense(400,activation="relu"))
encoder.add(Dense(200,activation="relu"))
encoder.add(Dense(100,activation="relu"))
encoder.add(Dense(50,activation="relu"))
encoder.add(Dense(25,activation="relu"))

from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense,Flatten,Reshape
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import SGD

decoder = Sequential()
decoder.add(Dense(50,input_shape=[25],activation='relu'))
decoder.add(Dense(100,activation='relu'))
decoder.add(Dense(200,activation='relu'))
decoder.add(Dense(400,activation='relu'))
decoder.add(Dense(28 * 28, activation="sigmoid"))
decoder.add(Reshape([28, 28]))

autoencoder = Sequential([encoder, decoder])
autoencoder.compile(loss="binary_crossentropy",optimizer=SGD(lr=1.5),metrics=['accuracy'])

autoencoder.fit_generator(train_image_gen,epochs=5,validation_data=[test_image_gen])
```

error:-

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-138-2ba76e38141b> in <module>
----> 1 autoencoder.fit_generator(train_image_gen,epochs=5,validation_data=[test_image_gen])

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py in fit_generator(self, generator, steps_per_epoch, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_data, validation_steps, validation_freq, class_weight, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, shuffle, initial_epoch)
   2207         'Please use `Model.fit`, which supports generators.',
   2208         stacklevel=2)
-> 2209     return self.fit(
   2210         generator,
   2211         steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch,

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py in error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
     65     except Exception as e:  # pylint: disable=broad-except
     66       filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.__traceback__)
---> 67       raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
     68     finally:
     69       del filtered_tb

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\execute.py in quick_execute(op_name, num_outputs, inputs, attrs, ctx, name)
     52   try:
     53     ctx.ensure_initialized()
---> 54     tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
     55                                         inputs, attrs, num_outputs)
     56   except core._NotOkStatusException as e:

InvalidArgumentError: Graph execution error:

Detected at node 'sequential_2/sequential/dense/Relu' defined at (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\Lenovo\anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 194, in _run_module_as_main
      return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
    File "C:\Users\Lenovo\anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
      exec(code, run_globals)
    File "C:\Users\Lenovo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py", line 16, in <module>
      app.launch_new_instance()
    File "C:\Users\Lenovo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\traitlets\config\application.py", line 845, in launch_instance
      app.start()
    File "C:\Users\Lenovo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelapp.py", line 612, in start
      self.io_loop.start()
    File "C:\Users\Lenovo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\platform\asyncio.py", line 199, in start
      self.asyncio_loop.run_forever()
    File "C:\Users\Lenovo\anaconda3\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 570, in run_forever
      self._run_once()
    File "C:\Users\Lenovo\anaconda3\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 1859, in _run_once
      handle._run()
    File "C:\Users\Lenovo\anaconda3\lib\asyncio\events.py", line 81, in _run
      self._context.run(self._callback, *self._args)
    File "C:\Users\Lenovo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\ioloop.py", line 688, in <lambda>
      lambda f: self._run_callback(functools.partial(callback, future))
    File "C:\Users\Lenovo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\ioloop.py", line 741, in _run_callback
      ret = callback()
    File "C:\Users\Lenovo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 814, in inner
      self.ctx_run(self.run)
    File "C:\Users\Lenovo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 775, in run
      yielded = self.gen.send(value)
    File "C:\Users\Lenovo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py", line 365, in process_one
      yield gen.maybe_future(dispatch(*args))
    File "C:\Users\Lenovo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 234, in wrapper
      yielded = ctx_run(next, result)
    File "C:\Users\Lenovo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py", line 268, in dispatch_shell
      yield gen.maybe_future(handler(stream, idents, msg))
    File "C:\Users\Lenovo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 234, in wrapper
      yielded = ctx_run(next, result)
    File "C:\Users\Lenovo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py", line 543, in execute_request
      self.do_execute(
    File "C:\Users\Lenovo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 234, in wrapper
      yielded = ctx_run(next, result)
    File "C:\Users\Lenovo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\ipkernel.py", line 306, in do_execute
      res = shell.run_cell(code, store_history=store_history, silent=silent)
    File "C:\Users\Lenovo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\zmqshell.py", line 536, in run_cell
      return super(ZMQInteractiveShell, self).run_cell(*args, **kwargs)
    File "C:\Users\Lenovo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2894, in run_cell
      result = self._run_cell(
    File "C:\Users\Lenovo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2940, in _run_cell
      return runner(coro)
    File "C:\Users\Lenovo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\async_helpers.py", line 68, in _pseudo_sync_runner
      coro.send(None)
    File "C:\Users\Lenovo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3165, in run_cell_async
      has_raised = await self.run_ast_nodes(code_ast.body, cell_name,
    File "C:\Users\Lenovo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3357, in run_ast_nodes
      if (await self.run_code(code, result,  async_=asy)):
    File "C:\Users\Lenovo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3437, in run_code
      exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
    File "<ipython-input-42-18f3c5f5c0d6>", line 1, in <module>
      autoencoder.fit(train_image_gen,epochs=5,validation_data=[test_image_gen])
    File "C:\Users\Lenovo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 64, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "C:\Users\Lenovo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1384, in fit
      tmp_logs = self.train_function(iterator)
    File "C:\Users\Lenovo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1021, in train_function
      return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "C:\Users\Lenovo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1010, in step_function
      outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    File "C:\Users\Lenovo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1000, in run_step
      outputs = model.train_step(data)
    File "C:\Users\Lenovo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 859, in train_step
      y_pred = self(x, training=True)
    File "C:\Users\Lenovo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 64, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "C:\Users\Lenovo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\base_layer.py", line 1096, in __call__
      outputs = call_fn(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
    File "C:\Users\Lenovo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 92, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "C:\Users\Lenovo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\sequential.py", line 374, in call
      return super(Sequential, self).call(inputs, training=training, mask=mask)
    File "C:\Users\Lenovo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\functional.py", line 451, in call
      return self._run_internal_graph(
    File "C:\Users\Lenovo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\functional.py", line 589, in _run_internal_graph
      outputs = node.layer(*args, **kwargs)
    File "C:\Users\Lenovo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 64, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "C:\Users\Lenovo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\base_layer.py", line 1096, in __call__
      outputs = call_fn(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
    File "C:\Users\Lenovo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 92, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "C:\Users\Lenovo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\sequential.py", line 374, in call
      return super(Sequential, self).call(inputs, training=training, mask=mask)
    File "C:\Users\Lenovo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\functional.py", line 451, in call
      return self._run_internal_graph(
    File "C:\Users\Lenovo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\functional.py", line 589, in _run_internal_graph
      outputs = node.layer(*args, **kwargs)
    File "C:\Users\Lenovo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 64, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "C:\Users\Lenovo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\base_layer.py", line 1096, in __call__
      outputs = call_fn(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
    File "C:\Users\Lenovo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 92, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "C:\Users\Lenovo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\layers\core\dense.py", line 233, in call
      outputs = self.activation(outputs)
    File "C:\Users\Lenovo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\activations.py", line 311, in relu
      return backend.relu(x, alpha=alpha, max_value=max_value, threshold=threshold)
    File "C:\Users\Lenovo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\backend.py", line 4956, in relu
      x = tf.nn.relu(x)
Node: 'sequential_2/sequential/dense/Relu'
Matrix size-incompatible: In[0]: [20,462894], In[1]: [784,400]
     [[{{node sequential_2/sequential/dense/Relu}}]] [Op:__inference_train_function_1654]
```

Comment: What is the value of image_shape?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

A couple of approaches that might be helpful could be:

- Using `fit` instead of `fit_generator` as latest Keras Version works well with got as well. Also, the error also mentions that; Line 2207.
- Giving `steps_per_epoch` as an argument when using the `fit_generator` method ([source](https://pyimagesearch.com/2018/12/24/how-to-use-keras-fit-and-fit_generator-a-hands-on-tutorial/)).

Excerpt from [the article](https://pyimagesearch.com/2018/12/24/how-to-use-keras-fit-and-fit_generator-a-hands-on-tutorial/).

> Keras data generator is meant to loop infinitely — it should never return or exit.
>
> Since the function is intended to loop infinitely, Keras has no ability to determine when one epoch starts and a new epoch begins.
>
> Therefore, we compute the `steps_per_epoch` value as the total number of training data points divided by the batch size. Once Keras hits this step count it knows that it’s a new epoch

Comment: This is not an answer as the problem has nothing to do with using fit or fit_generator. Basically this is just speculation.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).